# grep with colored output returns several empty lines

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe

I have strange issue with grep (2.12-2, debian testing).

In some situations when I do something like this:
`grep -rni '."spacer">.' .` grep return me several empty lines:

[image]

If I add `--color=none` all lines become visible.

grep options in .bashrc:

```
export GREP_COLORS='fn=01;34:ms=01;33:ln=33'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal file that causes this behavior? That way we could test to see if we get the same problem. Are the lines actually printed in your terminal? Do they appear if you select them?

Comment: No, lines aren't printed actually. Please check file: http://www.sendspace.com/file/39ouyh    and grep options: grep -rni '."spacer">.'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very useful tool for debugging this kind of thing is `od`. Passing the output of your `grep` command through `od` showed that your file contains DOS style line endings, carriage return (`\r`) followed by a new line (`\n`):

```
$ grep -i '."spacer">.' default.php | od -c
0000000  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t   <   d   i   v       c   l   a   s   s   =
0000020   "   s   p   a   c   e   r   "   >  \r  \n  \t  \t  \t   <   d
0000040   i   v       c   l   a   s   s   =   "   s   p   a   c   e   r
0000060   "   >  \r  \n
0000064
```

So, to test, I created this minimal test file:

```
$ echo -ne "<div class=\"spacer\">\r\n<div class=\"spacer\">\r\n" > foo.php
$ cat foo.php 
<div class="spacer">
<div class="spacer">
```

I confirmed that `grep` prints empty lines:

```
$ grep -i '."spacer">.' foo.php 


$
```

The *reason* it is printing empty lines is the carriage return (`\r`). You are asking `grep` to find the string `spacer">` **and the following character**. In your file, the following character is `\r`. Printing `\r` in the terminal has the effect of clearing the last line printed so it results in displaying an empty line. You can test this with the following command:

```
$ echo -e "foo\rbar"
bar
```

What actually happens is that first `foo` is printed, then deleted because of `\r` and replaced by `bar`. Check with `od`:

```
$ echo -e "foo\rbar" | od -c
0000000   f   o   o  \r   b   a   r  \n
0000010
```

---

Now, I don't understand why the `colors` option of `grep` is changing things. It must have something to do with how special characters are displayed. In any case, you can fix your problem by removing all  `\r`:

```
$ sed 's/\r//g' default.php > bar.php
```

Then, remove the last `.` from your grep pattern (remember that by default `.` does not match newlines although it does match `\r`):

```
$ grep -ni '."spacer">' bar.php 
103:                <div class="spacer">
222:            <div class="spacer">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, very interesting. Maybe report bug report for this issue?

Comment: @Sloan it's not really a bug, that's what `\r` is supposed to do.

Comment: Maybe, but if this isn't bug, why --color=auto/always do incorrect output?

Comment: I'm so late. Very old bug http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?25539